# How to make button width work in media query

Tags: html, css, button

I have 6 buttons in my code and i want them all the width the same and only the first button working. I tried using `width:auto important;` and I can't still override the remaining 5 buttons. Please help me. Thank you.

```css
#subpage .btn {
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 1%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #222;
}

#subpage .btn a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#subpage .b1 {
  width: 60%;
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#subpage .b2 {
  width: 45%;
}

#subpage .b3 {
  width: 28.3%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #subpage .btn {
    float: none;
    margin: 1% 7% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  #subpage .b1,
  #subpage .b2,
  #subpage .b3 {
    width: auto !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn b1"><a href="../sample.html">サンプルボタン</a></div>
<div class="btn b2"><a href="../sample.html">サンプルボタン</a></div>
<div class="btn b2"><a href="../sample.html">サンプルボタン</a></div>
<div class="btn b3"><a href="../sample.html">サンプルボタン</a></div>
<div class="btn b3"><a href="../sample.html">サンプルボタン</a></div>
<div class="btn b3"><a href="../sample.html">サンプルボタン</a></div>
```

Expected Result

[image]

Mine

[image]

Comment: I think it works fine. Have you tried to resize the window?

Comment: @Ibra Yes, I tried it many times.

Comment: You used a media query. It looks fine when the screen size is under 700px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in my problem. I put the `width:auto !important;` in `.btn` .And added `clear:both; float:none; margin:0 auto;` in `.b2, .b3` and and instead of `width:auto !important;` I resize it to `width:86% !important;`

```
#subpage .btn{
    float: none;
    margin: 2px 7% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

#subpage .b2,
#subpage .b3{
   clear: both;
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 86% !important;
}
```